# How to execute stored procedure in C# if I already have a DBContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I already have a `DBContext` created in my ASP.NET MVC project. Now I want to call a SQL command or a stored procedure in my `HomeController`. How can I do that?

This is what I tried to add in my `HomeCotroller`, but I get an error

> dbsdbEntities is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dtsdbEntities);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
                CommandText = "select getdate()"
            };

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Model:

```
namespace DBUpdateTool.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class dtsdbEntities : DbContext
    {
        public dtsdbEntities()
            : base("name=dtsdbEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<IPR_CompanyGen22> IPR_CompanyGen22 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the connection string in my `web.config` file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dtsdbEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DBModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=********,2431;initial catalog=**;persist security info=True;user id=***;password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an **instance** of your `dtsdbEntities` dbcontext, and then create the `SqlCommand` based on that - you cannot just pass the **type** of your dbcontext into a `SqlConnection` constructor.....

```
using (var ctx = new dtsdbEntities())
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT GETDATE()";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. But I got this error `can not implicitly convert type systerm.data.common.dbconnection to systerm.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection`. Do I miss something?

Comment: @ella: hmm.. I thought I had used that before - anyhoo, I updated my response, hope it'll work ( I don't have a chance to test it right now).